# Как изменить переменную GET через js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

Есть переменная в URL page, есть функция load в js
надо перед вызовом функции изменить переменную GET.
Например:

До вызова: domain.dom/?page=11

После вызова: domain.dom/?page=1

Comment: У вас есть доступ через window.location

Comment: Без перезагрузки!

Comment: window.history.replaceState